# When using the caption package and the capt-of package, the behaviors of the \captionof command are different?

Tags: captions, capt-of

When I use the `caption` package, the `\captionof` command only can be used in a group or an environment. But when I use the `capt-of` package, there are no warnings about using the `\captionof` command outsides a group or an environment. I already have read the caption package documentation but haven't found the information about this. Why is it?

By contrast：When I use the `caption` package and the `\captionof` command outsides a group or an environment, I have a warning:

```
Package caption Warning: \captionsetup{type*=...} or \captionof outside box or environment on input line XXX.See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

But when I use the `capt-of` package and the `\captionof` command outsides a group or an environment, there is nothing.

details:

1. format:LaTeX
2. engine:XeLaTeX
3. distribution:Overleaf

Comment: The warning is just a warning. It is for security only, because setting the caption type globally would e.g. also involve `\caption` outside floats. The `capt-of` package just does not warn for the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason here is that the packages have different authors, mainly. Moreover, the [`caption` package](//ctan.org/pkg/caption) also has a much larger scope than [`capt-of`](//ctan.org/pkg/capt-of). The `caption` package is considered the go-to for caption management, with the maintainer also writing [`subcaption`](//ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) and [`newfloat`](//ctan.org/pkg/newfloat) that works well with the `caption` package.

The `capt-of` package was written to almost circumvent the typical environment/float-bound captioning. It's a super-tiny, useful package that just defines

```
\newcommand\captionof[1]{\def\@captype{#1}\caption}
```

This just changes the `cap`tion `type` to whatever is supplied and then sets the `\caption`... allowing you to set a `\caption` wherever.